# JSF Target Unreachable, ''0'' returned null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

a list of Objects :

```
private ArrayList<LegBeanForInsert> listOfLegs;
```

I show this array by using the notation with arrays: 0 , 1 , .... positional for example:

```
                     <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{otcdEventsBean.listOfLegs[0].fixvar}"
                            effect="fade" style="width:100px; height:25px"
                            panelStyle="width:80px" >
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{otcdEventsBean.fixedVariableCodes}"  
                            itemValue="#{otcdEventsBean.listOfLegs[0].fixvar}" />
                            <p:ajax listener="#{otcdEventsBean.fixvarchange}" event="change" update="panelUpdate"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

ERROR:

```
value="#{otcdEventsBean.listOfLegs[0].fixvar}":  Target Unreachable, ''0'' returned null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
```

in the constructor of the bean i do:

```
 public void initLeg(){
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        LegBeanForInsert beanLeg = new LegBeanForInsert();

        beanLeg.setCallamount(new BigDecimal(0));

        beanLeg.setFixvar("");

        this.listOfLegs.add(beanLeg);
    }
}
```

this method is called by another page and when the page is renderd dose not have problem the page:

```
 public void setProduct(Object product1, Object product2) {
    System.out.println("BEGIN::setProduct: " + (String) product2);
    if (product1 instanceof EqdProduct) {
        this.eqdProdToedit = (EqdProduct) product1;

    } else if (product1 instanceof CURROPTRBTProduct) {
        this.rbtProdType = (CURROPTRBTProduct) product1;

    } else if (product1 instanceof COMAsianProduct) {
        this.comAsianProd = (COMAsianProduct) product1;

    } else if (product1 instanceof CRDProductType) {
        this.crdProduct = (CRDProductType) product1;

    } else if (product1 instanceof ComSwapProduct) {
        firstLegComSw = (ComSwapProduct) product1;

        if (product2 instanceof ComSwapProduct) {
            System.out.println("Com Sawp second prod");
            secondLegComSw = (ComSwapProduct) product2;
        }
    } else if (product1 instanceof List) {

        // bisogna settare LegBeanForInsert, LE GAMBE SONO 8 !!
        List<?> legs = (List<?>) product1;
        String s = (String) product2;
        System.out.println("setProduct 2nd arg: " + product2);

        if (s.equals("Legs")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < legs.size(); i++) {

                Leg leg = (Leg) legs.get(i);
                LegBeanForInsert beanLeg = new LegBeanForInsert();
                beanLeg.setCallamount(new BigDecimal(leg.getCallamount()));
                beanLeg.setCallcurrency(leg.getCallcurrency());
                beanLeg.setCallmaturity(leg.getCallmaturityNumber());
                beanLeg.setCodintord(leg.getCodintord());
                beanLeg.setDayconvention(leg.getDayconvention());
                beanLeg.setEnddate(leg.getEnddate());
                beanLeg.setEventcode(leg.getEventcode());
                beanLeg.setEventtype(leg.getEventtype());
                beanLeg.setExercisemode(leg.getExercisemode());
                beanLeg.setFixvar(leg.getFixvar());
                beanLeg.setEndDate(leg.getFmtenddate());
                beanLeg.setStartDate(leg.getFmtstartdate());
                beanLeg.setFrequency(leg.getFrequency());
                beanLeg.setFrequencymultiplier(leg.getFrequencymultiplier());
                beanLeg.setFrequencyunit(leg.getFrequencyunit());
                beanLeg.setInareas(leg.getInareas());
                beanLeg.setIndexname(leg.getIndexname());
                beanLeg.setMargin(leg.getMargin());
                beanLeg.setNotional(leg.getNotional());
                beanLeg.setNumber(leg.getNumber());
                beanLeg.setOptioncashdelivery(leg.getOptioncashdelivery());
                beanLeg.setOptionmaturity(leg.getOptionMatirityNumber());
                beanLeg.setOptiontype(leg.getOptiontype());
                beanLeg.setPaycurrency(leg.getPaycurrency());
                beanLeg.setPutamount(leg.getPutamount());
                beanLeg.setPutcurrency(leg.getPutcurrency());
                beanLeg.setPutmaturity(leg.getPutMatirityNumber());
                beanLeg.setQuantityunit(leg.getQuantityunit());
                beanLeg.setRate(leg.getRate());
                beanLeg.setRateconvention(leg.getRateconvention());
                beanLeg.setSign(leg.getSign());
                beanLeg.setStartdate(leg.getStartdate());
                beanLeg.setStrike(leg.getStrike());
                this.listOfLegs.add(beanLeg);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("MoneyD 2nd arg: " + product2);

            for (int i = 0; i < legs.size(); i++) {
                LegMoneyDeal leg = (LegMoneyDeal) legs.get(i);

                this.legMoneyD.add(leg);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // non nè nessuno di quelli bisogna settare a null tutto quanto
        otcdEvents = new OtcdEvents();
        crdProduct = new CRDProductType();
        firstLegComSw = new ComSwapProduct();
        secondLegComSw = new ComSwapProduct();
        comAsianProd = new COMAsianProduct();
        rbtProdType = new CURROPTRBTProduct();
        listOfLegs = new ArrayList<LegBeanForInsert>();
        legMoneyD = new ArrayList<LegMoneyDeal>();
        eqdProdToedit = new EqdProduct();
    }

}
```

the constructor :

```
  public OtcdEventsBean() {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        otcdEvents = new OtcdEvents();
        crdProduct = new CRDProductType();
        firstLegComSw = new ComSwapProduct();
        secondLegComSw = new ComSwapProduct();
        comAsianProd = new COMAsianProduct();
        rbtProdType = new CURROPTRBTProduct();
        ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myoracleDS");
        rederField = true;
        listOfLegs = new ArrayList<LegBeanForInsert>();
        initLeg();

        eqdProdToedit = new EqdProduct();
        legMoneyD = new ArrayList<LegMoneyDeal>();
        legMoneyD.add(new LegMoneyDeal());
        legMoneyD.add(new LegMoneyDeal());

        fieldsEditingDisabled = false;

        loginBean = (LoginBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "#{loginBean}", LoginBean.class);

        setFixedVariableCodes(new String[2]);
        getFixedVariableCodes()[0] = "Fixed";
        getFixedVariableCodes()[1] = "Variable";

        setSignPremiumCodes(new String[2]);
        signPremiumCodes[0] = "Pay";
        signPremiumCodes[1] = "Receive";

        setFrequencyUnitCodes(new String[4]);
        frequencyUnitCodes[0] = "day";
        frequencyUnitCodes[1] = "week";
        frequencyUnitCodes[2] = "month";
        frequencyUnitCodes[3] = "year";

        setCashDeliveryCodes(new String[2]);
        cashDeliveryCodes[0] = "C";
        cashDeliveryCodes[1] = "D";

        setOptionTypeCodes(new String[2]);
        optionTypeCodes[0] = "CALL";
        optionTypeCodes[1] = "PUT";
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

full bean code:

```
 http://pastebin.com/EbfuSwHN
```

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was misleading. The only thing I can come up with now is that your `listOfLegs` field is empty at the time given. Please post your managed bean definition to do a better analysis of the problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i post my full bean code

Comment: Try moving all your managed bean constructor logic into a `@PostConstruct public void init()` method, recompile your classes, redeploy your web application and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the init method called.  Maybe that is not getting called?  I do not see a new ArrayList on the definition.  When do you call new on ArrayList?  You should be getting a null pointer exception in the init method.  You could add the new ArrayList  to the beginning of the init method before the loop.  Remember also that set methods get called multiple times in JSF so you should limit the code in the set method.

Comment: it is called on inside the constructor

Comment: you are correct if i put it inside handleChange it works